# Manipulate giving errors when I plot the product of a step function and a continuous function

Tags: plotting, function-construction, manipulate, warning-messages, number-theory

Riemann's prime counting function `J` ([link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannPrimeCountingFunction.html)) takes half-values at every jump-discontinuity. So, I define it thus:

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
floor[e_] := Quiet[Check[Floor[e], Floor[FullSimplify[e]]]]; 
riemannJ[x_] :=
   With[{δ = 0.01}, 
     Piecewise[{
       {(Sum[(1/α)* PrimePi[(x - δ)^(1/α)],
        {α, 1, floor[Log[x - δ]/Log[2]]}] + Sum[(1/α)*
        PrimePi[(x + δ)^(1/α)], {α, 1, 
        floor[Log[x + δ]/Log[2]]}])/2,
        PrimePowerQ[x]},
       {Sum[(1/α)*PrimePi[x^(1/α)], {α, 1, 
       floor[Log[x]/Log[2]]}],
       True}
   }]];
```

Viewed as a `Plot`, the function `J[x]*x^(-s - 1)` produces a series of continuous lines that are discontinuous from each other at all points where `PrimePowerQ[x] = True` (plot shown with with `s = -2`):

```
Module[{s = -2}, 
 Plot[riemannJ[x]*x^(-s - 1), {x, 1, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic]
]
```

[image: plot with error: primepower argument is not exact number]

I have a couple of problems:

1. That error message: is Mathematica passing inaccurate values of `x` to `Plot`?
2. I'd like to use `Manipulate` to chart the curve for different values of `s`. But the plot now has a pink fill. The code is:

   ```
   Manipulate[
    Plot[riemannJ[x]*x^(-s - 1), {x, 1, 10}, GridLines -> Automatic], 
    {{s, -2, Style["Choose s", Larger, Bold]}, -5, 5, 1/2}, 
    ControlType -> Setter]
   ```

and the output:

[image: output of manipulate with same error and plot with pink background]

I assume that this is the same error (as evidenced but the line below the plot), only now it shows the plot in pink.

How do I get around this?

Lastly:

3. Is there a way to 'join up' the line segments at the points of discontinuity?

Comment: “ is Mathematica passing inaccurate values of x to Plot?” - Plot is passing machine-precision values to your function as it evaluates it in the plotting range you chose. Those values are passed to PrimePowerQ, which complains because its input should be arbitrary-precision. You should sanitize your inputs to riemannJ.

Comment: Hi @MarcoB. OK - but I have no idea how to do that...

Comment: oops, sorry @MarcoB - saw your comment after I posted.. Same answer

Comment: @GeorgeVarnavides Not a problem! I am glad you put together a proper answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PrimePowerQ` only takes exact numbers as arguments.

```
In[1]:= PrimePowerQ[1.2]
During evaluation of In[1]:= PrimePowerQ::exact: Argument 1.2` in PrimePowerQ is not an exact number.
Out[1]= PrimePowerQ[1.2]
```

`Plot` is happy to ignore the unevaluated `Piecewise` calls (which is why you also get the discontinuities).

All three questions are fixed by replacing `PrimePowerQ[x]` with `PrimePowerQ[Rationalize[x,0]]`.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.